# Searching for substrings in Java

Tags: java, file, search, text, substring

What I'm trying to do is as follows: I have a list of names (approximately 40,000) which will remain constant, and a text file (approx 10000 lines) that will change from search to search. I need to find a suitable way to search through each line in the text file to see if there is an exact string match between a name and the text and then return the matches and occurrences (see below). I've implemented this with a nested 'for loop' which is, as most probably know, very slow. I'm sure other have sought out this same question and I apologize if this question is repetitive, however, I have searched considerably for an appropriate answer and have thus far been unsuccessful. I would appreciate any assistance that can be offered (Java preferred). Note too that any structure which would speed up this search would be beneficial to me (doesn't have to be the best one). Sincere thanks for any help.

Example:

names.txt (static)
Andy Dick
Andrew Cunningham
.
.
.
Isaac P. Newton
.
.
.
Zulu

text.txt (dynamic)
This is the random text which may or may not contain any names such as Isaac P. Newton or Zulu. More lines here... Another Zulu...

I need to return the following:
Isaac P. Newton 1
Zulu 2

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Is this homework?
Use a Map to store the static names and number of ocurrences.

Comment: Unrelated, but my last name is Newton, and I went to high school with Andy. So there's that.

Comment: You can use lucene in your application but for that you have to index your documents first (your text files). Then search will be with lightning speed.

Comment: No, this is not for homework. Just trying to get some exposure to Java and programming.

Comment: Yes I've stumbled across Lucene, however, I was unable to find any coding I could understand. I'll definitely revisit it.

Comment: Lucene won't help you if the file is dynamic, you'd have to wait for it to be indexed before you could search it anyway. Your question isn't clear as to what "performance" you are currently getting and what performance is acceptable. If you're after elegance, try using [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap from Java where you load all the names in the names.txt to a HashMap and then search in it. It should improve your performance. Here is some sample code.

```
       HashMap<String, Integer> textNames = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
       for (String name : nameFile) {
           textNames.put(name, 0);
       }

       for (String line : textFile) {
           if (textNames.containsKey(line)) {
               textNames.put(line, textNames.get(line)+1);
           }
       }
```

--V

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest constructing a finite automaton out of the 40,000 names. In Java, you can do this by leveraging regular expressions. Construct a regular expression by concatenating each name with the "|" symbol.  Compile the pattern and match each input line against it.